# I am unable to get this SQL query to run. I don't know why it will not work, I am assuming that I have joined the two tables incorrectly

Tags: sql, oracle

```
SELECT orders.orderID, orders.customerID, orders.ShippedDate, customers.postalcode
FROM northwinds.customers, northwinds.orders
Where northwinds.orders.customerID= 
      northwinds.customers.customerID
Having PostalCode = 5020 OR PostalCode = 5022;
```

[Table Connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmiDY.png)

I just had to join the orders and customers tables, I tried doing that, but it appears that I have made a mistake.
I was expecting the code to deliver results that would organize the data in the tables by OrderID, CustomerID, ShippedDate, and PostalCode while only including those that had a PostalCode of 5022 or 5020

Comment: So I have added table names to everything thinking that might have been the issue. I can confirm that it is not.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (more than **30 years!!** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: On a sde note: Use table aliases to get the query more readable: `SELECT o.orderid, c.customerid, o.shippeddate, c.postalcode FROM northwinds.customers c INNER JOIN northwinds.orders o ON o.customerid = c.customerid WHERE c.postalcode IN ('5020', '5022') ORDER BY c.customerid, o.shippeddate;`